# Backup my files on every ftp change

Tags: linux, ftp, backup, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi with a webserver and ftpserver running. (apache and proftpd)
its just a little website, a playground.

I would like my files to be backed up every time I update/change them via FTP.
So when I upload my new, changed, html-file, the old one should be copied over in another directory, possibly with date and time in the filename.

I would then set a maximum number of files in this directory, so it doesn't fill up my whole space.

Like I said, it doesn't have to be perfect, it's just a small playgroud where I'm testing some things, but I would still like to have at least some earlier versions of the files available.

Thanks

Comment: I remember, there was something like callbacks for ProFTPd, that get called when a certain event occurs.

Comment: Can't you use some version control system like `git` ?

Comment: I have no experience with git. Can I use that for my html files which I edit via FTP?

Comment: You can push files to git via ssh.  Are you able to ssh to the system instead of FTP?

Comment: + for git. Also you can upload html via http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/ or http://www.noah.org/wiki/Rsync_backup. While rsyncing, they will keep also previous versions of files.